# UI Router $state.go throwing $stateChangeError

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm running into an issue (I think) with UI-Router v0.4.2 throwing the following error, when I attempt to run a `$state.go();`

> 14:57:22.563 Error: [$http:badreq] Http request configuration url must be a string.  Received: ["$stateParams",null]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$http/badreq?p0=%5B%22%24stateParams%22%2Cnull%5D
>   Stack trace:
>   minErr/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:68:12
>   $http@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:11439:15
>   createShortMethods/http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:11698:18
>   handleRequestFn@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:19419:14
>   TemplateFactory/this.fromUrl@http://localhost:3001/vendor.js:1488:16
>   TemplateFactory/this.fromConfig@http://localhost:3001/vendor.js:1444:39
>   load@http://localhost:3001/vendor.js:4586:20
>   resolveViews/http://localhost:3001/vendor.js:4479:20
>   invoke@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:4718:16
>   proceed@http://localhost:3001/vendor.js:1266:32
>   invoke@http://localhost:3001/vendor.js:1262:26
>   $Resolve/this.study/<@http://localhost:3001/vendor.js:1241:14
>   $Resolve/this.resolve@http://localhost:3001/vendor.js:1345:12
>   resolveViews/<@http://localhost:3001/vendor.js:4482:30
>   forEach@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:335:11
>   resolveViews@http://localhost:3001/vendor.js:4476:9
>   processQueue@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:16383:28
>   scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:16399:27
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:17682:16
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:17495:15
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:17790:13
>   ngEventHandler/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:25890:17
>   defaultHandlerWrapper@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:3497:3
>   createEventHandler/eventHandler@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:3485:9
>   1 script.js:1301:13   
>   http://localhost:3001/app/script.js:1301:13
>     $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:18005:15
>     transitionTo/$state.transition<
>   http://localhost:3001/vendor.js:4245:15   processQueue
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:16383:28
>     scheduleProcessQueue/<
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:16399:27
>     $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:17682:16
>     $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:17495:15
>     $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:17790:13
>     ngEventHandler/<
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:25890:17
>     defaultHandlerWrapper
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:3497:3
>     createEventHandler/eventHandler
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:3485:9

The route, looks like this:

```
.state('foo.bar', {
    url: '/:type/:id',
    views: {
        'question': {
            templateUrl: ['$stateParams', function (stateParams) {
                var qID = stateParams.id;
                var template = qID + '.tmpl.html';
                var url = "app/section/foo/";

                return qID <= 7 ? url + 'general/' + template : url + stateParams.type + "/" + template;
            }]
        }
    }
})
```

And I'm using this to try and go to the state:

```
$state.go('foo.bar', {
    type: 'typeA',
    id: 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Insert face palm]

Square Brackets on templateUrl: was causing the issue

```
templateUrl: function (stateParams) {
    var qID = stateParams.id;
    var template = qID + '.tmpl.html';
    var url = "app/section/foo/";

    return qID <= 7 ? url + 'general/' + template : url + stateParams.type + "/" + template;
}
```